# raspberry pi camera won't when called by php

Tags: php, permissions, raspberry-pi

I have been working with a R-pi 3b+ and raspberry camera v2 to try and play a video at a specific time (when I check a gpio slot on an input which is on another pi). I'll call the pi which should record with this piece of code.

```
os.system("curl --silent http://192.168.0.239/controllers/take-video.php &")
```

The php file it calls looks like this

```
<?php
system("/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/pi/Desktop/take-video.py");
echo("take video")
?>
```

When calling it from another pi it will echo "take video" but will not start captering the video. The python file it calls looks like this.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
from picamera import PiCamera

camera = PiCamera()


camera.start_preview()
camera.start_recording('/home/pi/Desktop/video.h264')
time.sleep(10)
camera.stop_recording()
camera.stop_preview()
exit()
```

If I call these files from the pi itself they work perfectly but when they are called from another pi they do not work. I think there is something with permissions that has to be solved.

I already added these rules to sudo visudo

```
www-data ALL(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
pi ALL(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And added www-data to the gpio group and video group with:

```
sudo usermod -a -G gpio www-data
sudo usermod -a -G video www-data
```

Calling a php file which refers to a python file which reboot works fine though.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That PHP script is called via webserver which is different than from calling from CLI. Try to put some output in your python script to see if it is called at all. Maybe a look into error.log (apache?) may give a hint.

Comment: I fixed it by just using the commandline function to record :
os.system("sudo raspivid -o /home/pi/Desktop/video.h264 -t 10000") by calling sudo it will have all rights it needs :) Thanks for your answer though helped a lot when I knew that I could watch apache error logs!

Comment: Always take care running a command with sudo, because you elevate it to root access.